fastAPI pydantic JSON input should be string error. Помогите
Всем привет. Подскажите, что не так.
fastAPI выглядит так:
class AnyJSON(BaseModel):
    json_obj: Json[Any]

@app.post("/newchips/")
async def newchips(old_chips: AnyJSON):
    return old_chips.json_obj;

Вызывается с фронта через XMLHttpRequest:
req = new XMLHttpRequest();
reqBody1 = {"chips" : "тест",
             "rules": "тест"
           };
reqBody1 = {"json_obj" : reqBody1};       
req.open("POST", "http://tttt/newchips/",true);
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
req.send(JSON.stringify(reqBody1));

Выдает ошибку:
"detail":[{"type":"json_type","loc":["body","json_obj"],"msg":"JSON input should be string, bytes or bytearray","input":{"chips":"тест","rules":"тест"}

Если поменять тип json_obj на str, то все равно ошибка:
{"type":"string_type","loc":["body","json_obj"],"msg":"Input should be a valid string","input":{"chips":"тест","rules":"тест"}

При этом в последнем случае, если передаваемый json простой:
reqBody1 = {"json_obj" : "тест"};

то все работает. Куда копать? Есть способ получить body не используя pydantic, но хотелось бы понять, как он валидирует и что не так.

Что за тип Json?

Json -a special type wrapper which loads JSON before parsing. https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/usage/types/json/ - You can use Json data type to make Pydantic first load a raw JSON string. Так у них в доке написано.

Такое будет работать, только если вы передадите внутри json_obj строку, в которую обернут json. На фронте будет что-то типа reqBody1 = {"json_obj" : JSON.stringify(reqBody1)};. Если вам просто произвольный вложенный объект нужно получить, то укажите json_obj: Any: https://i.sstatic.net/6N0ZpGBM.png

Круто. Заработало. Правда, до конца непонятно, почему произвольный объект отличается от строки.

Произвольный объект - это например словарь с ключами и значениями. Тип Json указывает, что в поле должен быть не сам словарь, а его json представление в виде строки (например, этот же словарь, обернутый в JSON.stringify()). В этом и разница.

Это я понял. Непонятно, почему когда тип str, то к строке не приводится, а выдаётся ошибка invalid string. json  в запросе это же строка всегда.

Потому что вы на фронте не строку передаете, а словарь (в терминах Python). Чтобы в поле str нормально конвертировалось, то и передавать нужно строку.

"json в запросе это же строка всегда" - нет, строка только в самом начале. Сначала json десериализуется из строки в Python представление - словарь, список и т.д., а потом уже значения из этого словаря в поля модели записываются.
